# Image deforming when setting on ImageView

Tags: android

In the app I'm delevoping, the user is able to get a photo from gallery or to take one directly from the camera, to set it as profile picture.

Then, this photo is shown in the profile page, where is placed in a way like this:

[image]

My testing phone is a HTC Sensation with KitKat 4.4.4. Here the pic shows Ok, but in my personal device, Galaxy S5 with 5.0, the pic doesn't show well. It fit's right the entire space, but appears deformed. If the image is in landscape, it get's narrowed, and if is in portrait, it get's broad.

This is the code I use for this proposal, in this case, taking the pic from the camera:

```
/*Get's data from onActivityResult*/
Bitmap srcBmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

Bitmap landBmp = null;
/*If it is square or portrait*/
if (srcBmp.getWidth() <= srcBmp.getHeight()) {
    landBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        srcBmp,
        0,
        srcBmp.getHeight()/4,
        srcBmp.getWidth(),
        srcBmp.getHeight() /2
    );
/*If is on landscape*/
} else {
    landBmp = srcBmp.copy(srcBmp.getConfig(), true);
}

/*Get screen dimensions*/
Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int screenWidth = size.x;
int screenHeight = size.y;

/*Bitmap scaling*/
int picOriginalWidth = srcBmp.getWidth();
int picOriginalHeight = srcBmp.getHeight();
Bitmap fullbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(landBmp, screenWidth, (originalHeight*screenWidth)/originalWidth, true);

//After this I save the pic on memory, this works fine so isn't relevant
...
```

So, maybe some of the operations need a correction to get well fitted, or there is a better way to do this?

EDIT--

Some things modificated in the above text. The problem is not that the Image doesn't fit the ImageView space. In fact, this is well done. The problem is that the image is getting resized and deformed.

Comment: user `scaleType="fitXY"` in `ImageView`

Comment: @Nilesh This makes the pic fit the entire space of the imageview, as it has ben doing until now. The problem is that hte image continues getting deformed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `centerCrop` and `adjustViewBounds` does the job.

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:id="@+id/picview"
        android:src="@drawable/header_default_full"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public final class FitWidthImageView extends ImageView {

    public FitWidthImageView(Context context) {
            super(context);
    }

    public FitWidthImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FitWidthImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            try {
                    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
                    if (drawable == null) {
                            setMeasuredDimension(0, 0);
                    } else {
                            int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
                            int height = width * drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() / drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
                            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
                    }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            }
    }
}
```

It´s just an implementation of the ImageView widget that fits the screen width.